# Grafana and input syntax error with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, grafana, grafana-variable

Good morning, I'm encountering an error while setting up a dashboard in Grafana using a Postgres db as datasource. The graph is based on the following query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(codice_intervento) 
FROM 
  suc_dati_gw.view_dashboard_interventi
WHERE 
  stato_intervento IS NOT NULL
  AND fornitore IS NOT NULL
  AND anno_intervento IS NOT NULL 
  AND mese_intervento IS NOT NULL
  AND anno_intervento in ($anno_intervento) 
  AND mese_intervento in ($mese_intervento)
```

variables are: `SELECT anno_intervento FROM suc_dati_gw.view_dashboard_interventi GROUP BY anno_intervento` and `SELECT mese_intervento FROM suc_dati_gw.view_dashboard_interventi GROUP BY mese_intervento`. The result is an error that says `db query error: pq: invalid input syntax for integer: ""`.

If I comment/remove the two lines with variables the query runs smooth, in `suc_dati_gw.view_dashboard_interventi` the two fields `anno_intervento` and `mese_intervento` are INTEGER, I really can't figure out why it gives me this error.

Comment: Inspect query sent to database (in menu of the panel Inspect>Query). If you'll have troubles understanding why it doesn't work, [edit] your question and include that query.